# Почему выводится undefined

Tags: переменные, javascript

Пытаюсь присвоить переменной параметр получаемый функцией:

```
    function listResults(entries) {
       var gStr = '';
       var file_i = 0;
       var dir_i = 0;

       entries.forEach(function(entry) {
          if (entry.isDirectory) {
              //gStr += 'dir_' + dir_i + '=' + entry.name + " ";
              //dir_i++;
           } else {
            /***last modificated date*/
            var lastFileModDate = function(metadata) {
                //console.log("Last date: " + metadata.modificationTime);
                modificationTimes += metadata.modificationTime;
            }

            /**file size*/
            var fileSize = function(file) {
                //console.log("File size: " + file.size);
                fileSizes += file.size; 
            }

             modificationTimes = entry.getMetadata(lastFileModDate, fail);
             fileSizes = entry.file(fileSize, fail);
             gStr += 'file_' + file_i + '=' + entry.name +
                     ' date_file_' + file_i + '=' + modificationTimes + 
                     ' file_size_' + file_i + '=' + fileSizes + " | ";
             file_i++;
          }
    });
   }
```

она снова становится `undefined`. Что можно сделать, чтобы она не теряла данных?

вот даже пример привел выводит undefined http://jsfiddle.net/vL5nF/ почему так?

```
    var a;
var p = function(m) {
 a = m + 2;   
}
    document.write(p(3));
```

Для тех кому лень пойти по ссылке
​

Comment: Опять вы ^_^

Вам не надоело мучатся? Прочтите хотя-бы JS Good Parts и посмотрите видео Крокфорда. Видите-же что не складывается у вас с JS

Comment: Да, @AlexWindHope, без этого никуда ныне...

Comment: @dajver, а что за

    ' date_file_' + file_i + '=' + modificationTime +   
Куда этот кусок возвращает результат и зачем ^_^

Comment: Код исправил, и из советов я так и не понял как мне решить эту проблему. Все равно когда я пишу modificationTimes += metadata.modificationTime; у меня так же равно undefined

Comment: "становится undefined"... Вот же переменная стерва :D

Comment: >даже пример привел

а чего вы ожидали от функции без ``return``'a?

     return a = m + 2;   

и будет вам нормальный результат, но когда вы уже поймёте, что просто задавая невразумительные вопросы на этом или любом другом ресурсе, понимать происходящие в ваших скриптах вы не сможете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зайдите на [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru/) и освойте хотя бы основы JavaScript'а
Ваш вопрос совершенно не корректный (я удивляюсь как его до сих пор не заминусовали...)
А по поводу кода так все переменные подчинятся обычным законам ООП:

```
var modificationTime = 0;
function lastFileModDate(metadata) {
    return metadata * 5;
}
alert('modificationTime: ' + modificationTime + '\n'
+ 'lastFileModDate: ' + lastFileModDate + '\n'
+ 'lastFileModDate(5): ' + lastFileModDate(5) + '\n');
```

P.S Например у каждой ф-ции(она обьект) есть метод toString() это ООП:

```
function a(b){return b*5;} // a - это обьект
alert(a);    
a = function(b){
    return b*5;
}
a.toString = function(){return "Секрет..."}; // вот доказательство
alert(a);
alert(a(5));
```

Comment: законы ООП?

Comment: Да же не так а так:

    function a(b){return b*5;}
    alert(a);    
    a = function(b){
        return b*5;
    }
    a.toString =function(){return "Секрет..."};
    alert(a);
    alert(a(5));

Comment: Хочу заметить что автор вопроса хочет получить не возвращённое значение (его функция кстати возвращает null) а возвращённое значения метода toString объекта a (JS без оператора вызова ("()") для всех объектов пытается вызвать toString()) поэтому он называется ***Java***Script. Кто здесь нибудь имеет представление о ООП?   
@Котик_хочет_кушать вам бы всё пояснил наверное...

Comment: о **законах** ООП даже @Котик не слышал

> JS без оператора вызова ("()") для всех объектов пытается вызвать toString()

    var a = function(){...};
    var b = function(c){...};
    b(a);

неужели в переменной `с` будет `a.toString()`? наверно из-за таких вольных трактований поведения js, книги отечественных авторов не рекомендуются к прочтению

Comment: Вы поняли что я имел в виду @Spectre и не надо ёрничать когда не знаете JS как следует...

Comment: Да уж :)
**JavaScript — прототипно-ориентированный скриптовый язык программирования.** Он не является объектно-ориентированным. В нем нет классов - только объекты-прототипы.

Так же интересно откуда информация, что 
>(его функция кстати возвращает null)
может все-таки undefined?

Comment: Я же говорю зайдите на [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru "почитать") почитайте... null == undefined и null !== undefined и т.д.

Comment: Я не считаю "javascript.ru" за мегаресурс когда есть в сети более достойные англоязычные ресурсы. Не надо навязывать откуда черпать информацию. И если функция без инструкции return возвращает undefined , то не надо это называть null ибо null !== undefined (как вы сами заметили). То что при таком сравнении null == undefined произойдет преобразование типов, не дает право писать ошибочные комментарии с обвинением остальных в незнании JS :)

Comment: @Spectre \*Пошел в срочном порядке читать про законы ООП\*

Comment: Видимость переменных как-то не зависит ни от законов Объектно-ориентированного программирования, ни от законов Организации Освобождения Палестины.

Answer (score 0):

Все функции создают собственные пространства имен.

Вы объявили глобальную переменную `modificationTime`.

Далее в функции присвоили ей значение и на этом этапе в функции у вас одно значение этой переменной (которое вы присвоили), а вне функции осталось изначальное - в данном случае `undefined`.

Далее вы пытаетесь работать с глобальной переменной в другой функции и там она, естественно, `undefined`.

**UPD:** Как правильно заметил [[[[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov), все вышесказанное ошибочно (за исключением первого пункта).

Варианта при котором `modificationTime` остается `undefined` все 2 вижу:

1. Вы объявили переменную внутри функции и там же ее меняли, а позже пытались использовать за пределами области видимости (такой случай на примере показал [[[[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov) ниже).
2. `entry.getMetadata();` вызывается раньше чем `lastFileModDate()`.

Попробуйте поменять `"var modificationTime;"` на `"var modificationTime=0;"` и проделать то же самое. Если будет вставляться 0 - значит вы не меняете значение этой переменной. Если же будет по прежнему `undefined` - значит эту переменную не видит функция `entry.getMetadata()`.

Comment: т.е. вы считаете, что изменить значение глобальной переменной внутри функции нельзя? это неверное утверждение. вот если бы в функции была бы объявлена еще одна переменная с таким же названием, то ее изменение, да, не затронуло бы глобальную переменную.

скорее всего ошибка возникла примерно из-за такого кода:

    function foo(){
      var a=0;
      function foobar(){a++;}
      foobar();//a==1
    }
    bar(a);// a - undefined

Comment: Полностью согласен, поменять значение переменной из функции можно. Время было позднее и сам себя запутал :) Из приведенного примера сложно понять, что, где и как именно инициализируется и вызывается.

Comment: modificationTime выдает 0, когда modificationTime=0;

Comment: В таком случае у вас не происходит выполнение функции lastFileModDate.

entry.getMetadata(lastFileModDate, fail); - здесь вы передаете в getMetadata функцию, а не результат ее выполнения. Возможно поможет вот такой вариант:

entry.getMetadata(lastFileModDate(), fail);

Хотя лучше в lastFileModDate добавить явное возвращение значения. А в целом сложно по скудным данным из вопроса понять проблему. Нужно больше кода для анализа :) Как заметил @Rules не понятно откуда этот кусок кода "' date_file_' + file_i + '=' + modificationTime +"

Comment: исправил код, на полный, gStr это переменная в которую я загружаю все данные и отправляю на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

> Для тех кому лень пойти по ссылке ​

Те, кому лень пойти по ссылке отвечают, что задающему лень хоть чуть-чуть подумать. Нет в функции `return` - вот и держи свой `undefined`.